# android mobile app + micorosoft health-vault?

Tags: android, health-monitoring, healthvault

Any help/tutorial for a simple android mobile application that sends some values to health-vault.
Has anyone tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://healthvaultjavalib.codeplex.com/, specifically the bit about Android support at the bottom.